# Insert Select Option Form Laravel - Vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I wanna input data to database from Select Option Form. I used Laravel and Vue. 
This is my Form

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Pemilihan*</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="electionId" name="electionId" v-model="electionIdSelected">
     <option v-for="option in electionIdOptions" v-bind:value="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

This is my Vue:

```
data() {
          return{
                 electionIdSelected:'Please choose one',
                 electionIdOptions:[
                   {text: 'Presiden', value: 'ppwp'},
                   {text: 'DPRD Provinsi', value: 'pdpr'}
                 ],
           methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                axios.post('/psu/list/store', {
                   electionIdSelected: this.electionIdSelected,
                }).then(response => {
                   this.electionIdSelected = ''
             });
            }
```

This is my Controller in Laravel:

```
public function store(){
      $psu = new Psu;

      $psu->jenis_pemilihan = request('electionId');

      $psu->save();
    }
```

Please help me to insert form Select option into database. I still got error.
This is an Error Message:

```
null value in column "jenis_pemilihan" violates not-null constraint
```

Cant get value to Controller and Model.

Comment: what error are you facing. please mention also.

Comment: Good question, would be perfect if you could share exactly what the error told you.

Comment: The js for your vue component seems to be missing some `}`

Comment: Like @vahdet said, you need to elaborate on the error, or there's not much to answer.

Comment: Thank you for respond. I already update Error Message

Comment: Thank you for respond. I already update Error Message @H45H

Comment: Thank you for respond. I already update Error Message @MTran

Comment: have you fulfilled you model  `protected $fillable = [.... fields ...];` requirements.

Comment: Still same error @H45H

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request){
  $psu = new Psu;

  $psu->jenis_pemilihan = $request->input('electionIdSelected');

  $psu->save();
}
```

I think electionId is empty in your controller because you never set such a key in the axios post ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send electionIdSelected.text for that your selectbox model is electionIdSelected when u set your option.text to the model then your values look like `electionIdSelected.text`

Just replace this line : 
`electionIdSelected: this.electionIdSelected` to `electionIdSelected: this.electionIdSelected.text`